# How do I let a user edit the textcontent of a specific cell in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to programming, and I'm creating a website where a user can enter information about their favourite books into a table.

However I've been trying to add an edit button feature where a user can click a button on a specific cell of the table and then be prompted to write in the replacement information.

So for example if they've already entered in the name of an author, they can click the edit button next to the info in the cell and they'll be prompted to enter in the replacement author's name, and it'll then reset the info in the cell in the table.

```
function addBooks() {

//Below is adding the users input information to the table.

  let info = document.getElementById("author").value;
  let info2 = document.getElementById("title").value;
  let info3 = document.getElementById("genre").value;
  let info4 = document.getElementById("review").value;

  document.getElementById("author").value = "";
  document.getElementById("title").value = "";
  document.getElementById("genre").value = "";
  document.getElementById("review").value = "";

  let obj = {
    author: info,
    title: info2,
    genre: info3,
    review: info4,
  };

  let table = document.getElementById("table");

  const row = table.insertRow(1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

  //Below is the delete button which deletes a specific book/row.

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
  deleteButton.type = "button";
  deleteButton.textContent = "Delete Book";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    var row = deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  });

  cell1.innerHTML = `${obj.author}<button class="edit">Edit</button>`;
  cell2.innerHTML = `${obj.title}<button class="edit">Edit</button>`;
  cell3.innerHTML = `${obj.genre}<button class="edit">Edit</button>`;
  cell4.innerHTML = `${obj.review}<button class="edit">Edit</button>`;
  cell4.appendChild(deleteButton);

//Below here I am trying to addEvent listeners to the edit buttons that activate a function where the user can re-edit and enter new information into a specific cell.

  const editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("edit");

  for (var i = 0; i < editButtons.length; i++) {
    editButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      editButtons.parentNode.innerHTML = prompt("Enter corrected info:");
    });
  }
}
```

Above is the Javascript code, but when I click on an edit button I get this error in the console :

```
books.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (books.js:47:40)
```

I'm not sure what this means, but I was trying to be able to edit the text content of the parentNode. Is this the right way to to access and rewrite the text in the tables cells?

Here is also my html for reference.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="heading">Your Books</h1>

      <p class="subHeading">Author</p>
      <input type="text" id="author" />

      <p class="subHeading">Title</p>
      <input type="text" id="title" />

      <p class="subHeading">Genre</p>
      <input type="text" id="genre" />

      <p class="subHeading">Reviews</p>
      <input type="text" id="review" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="addBooks()" id="button">Submit</button>

    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Reviews</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="books.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I hope that I've phrased things clear enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `contentEditable="true"` on the cell of your choice?

Comment: @Robo Not saying Prompt is a viable solution, but contenteditable is a nightmare on its own. From inner tags, etc.

Comment: By doing parentNode.innerHTML you're getting rid of the edit button as well - just for the  sake of putting some new content. The values text should be in a separate tag on their own. Like a `<span>` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to fix the edit button so that it would remain functional no matter how many times it was used.

```
  const editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("edit");

  for (var i = 0; i < editButtons.length; i++) {
    editButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      editButtons.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML = prompt("Enter corrected info:");
    });
  }
}
```

This is the code that was used for the edit button function!

Answer (score 0):

- Never use `innerHTML` from unsanitized user inputs. Use `textContent` instead.
- Function *`addBooks`* should be named `addBook`. Singular.
- Use `<thead>` and specifically `<tbody>` as your target table element to insert rows into
- Assign events on Element creation.
- Create a separate `ELNew_TD` function to ease repetitive tasks
- (TODO: don't use `prompt()` )

Here's a quick remake using some nifty DOM helper functions to make the code more readable:

```js
// DOM utility functions

const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

// TASK:

const EL_author = EL("#author");
const EL_title = EL("#title");
const EL_genre = EL("#genre");
const EL_review = EL("#review");
const EL_table = EL("#table tbody");
const EL_add = EL("#button");

const ELNew_TD = (val) => {
  const EL_td = ELNew("td");
  const EL_span = ELNew("span", {
    textContent: val
  });
  const EL_edit = ELNew("button", {
    type: "button",
    className: "delete",
    textContent: "Edit",
    onclick() {
      val = prompt("Enter corrected info:");
      val && (EL_span.textContent = val);
    }
  });
  EL_td.append(EL_span, EL_edit);
  return EL_td;
};

const addBook = () => {
  const EL_tr = ELNew("tr");
  const EL_btnDel = ELNew("button", {
    type: "button",
    textContent: "Delete",
    onclick() { EL_tr.remove(); },
  });
  const EL_td5 = ELNew("td");
  EL_td5.append(EL_btnDel);

  EL_tr.append(
    ELNew_TD(EL_author.value),
    ELNew_TD(EL_title.value),
    ELNew_TD(EL_genre.value),
    ELNew_TD(EL_review.value),
    EL_td5,
  );

  EL_table.append(EL_tr);

  // Clear form
  EL_author.value = "";
  EL_title.value = "";
  EL_genre.value = "";
  EL_review.value = "";
};


EL_add.addEventListener("click", addBook);
```

```css
label {display: block; padding: 5px 0;}
label span {display: inline-block; min-width: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">Your Books</h1>
  <label><span>Author</span><input type="text" id="author"></label>
  <label><span>Title</span><input type="text" id="title"></label>
  <label><span>Genre</span><input type="text" id="genre"></label>
  <label><span>Reviews</span><input type="text" id="review"></label>
</div>

<button class="btn" id="button">Add Book</button>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Reviews</th><th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, use the “e” parameter you are passing into the event handler function to reference the elements (e.target).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Now it's replacing the text context. But it's removing the edit button as that's part of the innerHtml.